# Excel If function with the and condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to calculate some payroll taxes based on the state certain employees are in and I am getting results that I shouldn't be based on a fairly simple IF AND statement.  As you can see in columns N - Qif have the same formula except I have updated the state to match and the columns it is pulling from.  On row 8, I should only be getting a result in column N but I am getting a result in all four columns.  I have not pulled the formula down because I know there is an error.  Can someone help?

My formula:

```
=IF(AND($B8="CA",$K8<$O$3),$K8*$O$4,$O$3*$O$4)
```

column B = State, K = Gross Salary, row 3 is the wage threshold for that tax, and row 4 is the tax % to calculate.  The formula in this cell indicates that B8 should equal CA but on this particular row, the data in that field is WA and yet I am getting a result in that CA column.

[image]

Comment: I think you want a nested if instead: `=IF($B8="CA",IF($K8<$O$3,$K8*$O$4,$O$3*$O$4) )`

Comment: Scott Craner that did it!!   Thank you SO much!!

Comment: Just an FYI: you can simplfy: `=IF($B8="CA",MIN($K8,$O$3)*$O$4,"")`

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste your formula across multiple cells the absolutes `$` stay focused on those cells and don't change even if your in a new column. You need to remove some of the absolutes `$` if you want the formula to adjust to another column.

It appears that you have many states so I would use *if the row 2 (State) SUI Tax matches what is in Column B*. You should also test just your `AND()` by itself to make sure it is working right.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(FIND($B5,O$2)),$K5<O$3)
```

After texting that finish the `IF()`. It is not clear to me what you want returned for the `IF()` True and False. If you want more help post a comment if you are satisficed with the answer check the checkmark.